# play framework version 1.2.4

Tags: java, playframework

i'm new to play framework using java. I decided to start with a simple To-do list. I found some documentation online but only supporting play 2.0 and they are importing views and using the predefined ToDo method, problem is i'm only working on version 1.2.4 so any help about what can be used instead of importing views and using ToDo the redefined method?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the documentation version at the top of the page. I have already change the version to 1.2.4 for you: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need to work on 1.2.4 not 2.0 which is still a beta version

Comment: @Coder I understand that, which is why I posted a link to the 1.2.4 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the [YABE blog engine tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home#guide) for 1.2.4. After finishing this, you should be able to create a TODO list type of application.